# BlueStack stuck in loading page in VirutalBox Windows 7

Tags: loading, bluestacks

I tried to install BlueStack!

The same setup worked fine in my desktop, but My Virtual Machine (VirtualBox Windows7) didn't.

Is there a configuration for my virtual machine I could do?

Comment: Could you please more describe why you can't install BlueStack on VM? There are any errors?

Comment: it stuck on "Initializing" screen! just after download game data.